# Issue with viewport in mobile, content is cutting in mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I defined a `viewport` of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is the `html` and `body` style:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html,
section {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

My problem is that in mobile the content cuts and doesn't fit the screen,
like the following example

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening anyone can assist?

Thanks.

Comment: for a responsive design please use CSS Media Queries. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Can you please share your complete HTML, or creating a fiddle would be better.

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/roniitzhaik/e2pdr4r8/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not all of your css is available, I guess that your content has a fixed `width` or a `min-width`. Just try to give this a `max-width: 100%;` and your problem should be solved. *(If a `min-width` is present and is not absolutely necessary, it should also be removed.)*

Basically `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow-x: hidden;` does not mean that a kind of "wall" is build where the content stops. Rather, it means:

> Content **is clipped** if necessary to fit the padding box. No scrollbars are provided.
>
> *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow*

You also may have to adjust the `padding` or `margin` of the content for the suitable viewport. For this you can check the link in the comment from *@Libin C Jacob*.

Comment: here is the full css and html https://jsfiddle.net/roniitzhaik/e2pdr4r8/4/   I tried what u said but it doesn't change

Comment: Please look at the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784940/7426156) from @Hiral, she give you the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on CSS at various places. Like below :

```
#mission p{
  width:100%;
    max-width: 420px;
       float:left;
        padding-top:26px;
         text-align: left;
         font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.64;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #383836;
}
#secure p{
  width:100%;
       max-width: 420px;
      padding-bottom: 189px;
        padding-top:28px;
         text-align: left;
         font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.64;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #383836;
}
html, section{
    max-width: 100%;
overflow: auto;

}
```

**Tip :**

you are not supposed to use fix width of any section or component if you plan for responsive screen.

Kindly refer the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e2pdr4r8/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Some basic steps to better responsive design:

```
body * {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You should avoid using overflow hidden unless necessary.

Also, you've horizontal scrollbar below because there are 2 columns at the bottom bigger than viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

You cand use @media-query to define/adjust width/height or what you what to do at any resolution.

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  section {
    width: 100px;
}
```

This one is saying for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of 632px apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the other available media types the most common other one being print.